# PHP - How to control a Solaris server from php to run root commands to execute scripts?

Tags: php

Am a newbie in PHP.

I wanted to have a dropdown list for specific solaris servers, in which when a server is selected from the drop down list, the server will execute a script on itself. How do I even do that?

```
 <?php

session_start();

echo ("Select a Solaris System to audit");

?>

<form action="report.php" method="POST">

 <div>
 <select name="options">
      <option value="1">Solaris 001</option>
      <option value="2">Solaris 002</option>
      <option value="3">Solaris 003</option>
 </select>
 <br>
 <br>

 <input type="submit" value="Audit"/>

 </div>
</form>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: it all depends on what your script is going to do, use post to get your values

Comment: In addition to @Ibu you could redirect to a http page on the Solaris box, however the issue you are going to have is that on a correctly configured box you will not be able to access anything for the root user through apache/php. So yes, it does depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, important disclaimer :)

**Note, `shell_exec` used in a backend is rather dangerous function, as it might pose security threats. Isolate `shell_exec` from user input as much as possible and apply strict security policies**

You have to implement two "artifacts":

1. On each server you need a backend file that execute desired script. This file should be accessible over the network. Lets say it's accessible via url `http://*solarisservername*/justdoit` It might be something like

   ```
   //Check for authentication, if authenticated set $authenticated = true
   if ($authenticated){
       $script_response = shell_exec("<script to execute>");
   }
   //if you need, you may return result to the calling script
   //I'm using json format, but you may want to use plain text, XML or whatever.
   $result = array("script_response"=>$script_responce,"success"=>true);
   echo json_encode($result);
   ```
2. On your page you need to implement quering the URL we set up in a previous step. You have two options: using `cURL` and using `AJAX`. I'll describe `AJAX` method with `jQuery` as it is much simpler and fancy :). Note, it's Javascript

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#submit").click(function(){
           var url = $("select[name='options']").val();
           url = url + "justdoit"; //url now contains http://*solarisservername*/justdoit
           $.ajax({
               type:post,
               dataType: 'json'
               url: url,
               success: function(data,textStatus){
                   //process your response here
                   //access script response as data.script_response.
               }
           });
       });
   });
   </script>
   <!--you dont't need method and action here, as we don't even post the form-->
   <form>
    <div>
    <select name="options">
         <option value="http://solarisserver1">Solaris 001</option>
         <option value="http://solarisserver2">Solaris 002</option>
         <option value="http://solarisserver3">Solaris 003</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
   <!--onclick='return false' prevents form from submitting-->
    <input type="submit" id='submit' onclick='return false' value="Audit"/>

    </div>
   </form>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your report.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['options'])){
   // you can get value now
   $server = $_POST['options'];

   echo $server; // will print the current selected value
}
```

Comment: The server will execute a IT security auditing script once the selection is done on the dropdown list. How do i even access the server's terminal to execute the script? Or can I place the script on my own server and then call it to audit the other servers?